# Para que serve o metodo protected void service do Servlet e o motivo de não poder sobrescrever ele?

Tags: servlet

Gostaria de saber o motivo de não poder sobrescrever o metodo service? No livro use a cabeça ele fala que não se deve sobrescrever ele, mas por que? Mas se eu usar o super.service(request, response) eu não vou está chamando o metodo acima do que eu estou sobrescrevendo e com isso eu executarei além do meu service sobrescrito eu executarei o metodo raiz? Eu falo isso, pelo fato de eu querer instanciar minhas classes dentro do service, pois a cada solicitação do usuario a essa servlet esse service é invocado e instacia meus objetos, não tendo problema de um valor de um usuario x interverir no valor do usuario y. Essas classes instaciada são responsaveis de fazer a comunicação com o DAO e o servlet(É uma classe intermediária).

Answer (score 2):

Você entra em contradição pois primeiro fala que não dá para sobrescrever o método `service()` e depois fala que chama ele sobrescrito.

Ele pode ser sobrescrito, mas isso não é necessário.

Como diz a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-):

> Receives standard HTTP requests from the public service method and dispatches them to the doXXX methods defined in this class. This method is an HTTP-specific version of the Servlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) method. There's no need to override this method.

Em outras palavras, o `service()` é o método que efetivamente é chamado para atender as requisições que os clientes fazem para o servlet. Porém ele não é o responsável final pelo atendimento: ele também repassa as chamadas para métodos como `doGet()` ou `doPost()`, estes sim podendo ser sobrescritos por você (para atender requisições GET ou POST, respectivamente).

A arquitetura é basicamente essa, não há muito o que explicar. Lembrando que 99,9% do tempo você vai estar trabalhando com subclasses de `HttpServlet` e não de `Servlet`.